# building dynamic table from json serialized list object

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to get a serialized json list via ajax and create dynamic table in a html jquery mobile page. the list comes from a sql database in code behind.
I just don't know if I'm returing the json object right, and how to access it from the ajax success function.

My goal is to create dynamically a table of all the members in the html.

**I created a Member class:**

```
public class Member
{
    public Member()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }

    public String fName { set; get; }

    public String lName { set; get; }



}
```

**This is my function to return the member list in code behind:
(written in a class that connects with the sql)**

```
public List<Member> return_member_list()
    {
        List<Member> member_list = new List<Member>();

        String fName;
        String lName;


        SqlConnection user_con = connect("ActConString");
        SqlCommand user_command = create_command(user_con, "select m_first_name, m_last_name from member");

        SqlDataReader rdr = user_command.ExecuteReader();


        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            Member m1 = new Member();
            fName = Convert.ToString(rdr["m_first_name"]);
            lName = rdr["m_last_name"].ToString();


            m1.fName = fName;
            m1.lName = lName;



            member_list.Add(m1);


        }

        rdr.Close();
        user_con.Close();

        return member_list;
    }
```

**then I use an aspx page web method to return the list serialized:**

```
   [WebMethod]
    public static String return_member_list()
    {
        dbservices db1 = new dbservices();

        List<Member> member_list = db1.return_member_list();

        var jsonSerialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        var json = jsonSerialiser.Serialize(member_list);

        return json;
    }
```

**and the ajax:**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {



            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "getdata.aspx/return_member_list",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",

                success: function (res) {

                    //this is where I need help


                },
                error: function (res, msg, code) {
                    // log the error to the console
                    alert("The following error occured: " + msg + " " + code);
                } //error

            });

        });
```

I'd appriciate help with creating the table dynamically as well : )

Comment: can you give me your sample JSON response you receive?

Comment: [{\"fName\":\"ליבי\",\"lName\":\"פנינ\"},{\"fName\":\"אפרת\",\"lName\":\"אוחנה\"},{\"fName\":\"דביר\",\"lName\":\"ריזנמן\"},{\"fName\":\"ודים\",\"lName\":\"ודימוביץ\"},{\"fName\":\"לינור\",\"lName\":\"אבני\"}]"                                                                       there are names here in hebrew so just refer to it as names : ]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do the success function as below

```
success: function (res) {
    var parsedData = JSON.parse(res.d);
    var tableStr = "<table>";
    $.each(parsedData, function(){
        tableStr +="<tr><td>"+this.fName+"</td><td>"+this.lName+"</td></tr>";
    });
    tableStr += "</table>";
    $('#tableDiv').html(tableStr);
}
```

Assumes that you have a div with the id `tableDiv`